# React js index.html react props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

error:react props not found

How can i access react props in index.html page.the main page where i want to render some meta tags property. meta tags is come from back end.

I want to get my store data in index.html page.index.html is not a component so how can i do this.

Comment: You should provide your code.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong with your code when you haven't provided any! Please review [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help as you didn't provide any code in the first place. Hope what follows helps.

First install `react-meta-tags` by running `npm i react-meta-tag --save`. Then create a component as shown below: code taken from [react-meta-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags)

```
import React from 'react';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

class Metas extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
          <div>
              <MetaTags>
                  <title>{props.title}</title>
                  <meta name="description" content={props.description} />
                  <meta property="og:title" content={props.og-title} />
                  <meta property="og:image" content={props.og-image} />
              </MetaTags>
          </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Then you can use this component in another component like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Metas from './Metas'

class UseMeta extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Metas 
                title="Awesome website"
                description="Awesome description about my website"
                og-title="Another description"
                og-image="./public/img/awesome-image.png"
            />
        )
    }
}
```

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'))
The `UseMeta` will automatically be added to your html as long as you have an `id="root"` in your html like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./UseMeta.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You might need to make use of babel. For a complete tutorial, take a look at [Setup React.js with Npm, Babel 6 and Webpack in under 1 hour](https://medium.com/@fastlane80/setup-react-js-with-npm-babel-6-and-webpack-in-under-1-hour-1a714f973506)